# How do you get Highcharts to scale up image contents rather than add more details?

Tags: highcharts, itext

I am trying to generate PDF documents server side containing data tables and charts generated by HighCharts. I am using [highchart-serverside-export](https://github.com/one2team/highcharts-serverside-export) and [iText](http://itextpdf.com/).

I have been able to generate the documents but the chart images are grainy when printed. From what I understand, iText uses 72dpi by default when inserting an image. The correct way to get higher fidelity images is to start with a larger image and scale it down using one of the scaling functions such as [`scalePercent()`](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/Image.html#scalePercent%28float%29).

I can easily generate a larger chart image by passing in larger height and width parameters to Highcharts. The problem is that when you increase the dimensions of the chart, the content does not scale up (eg. font size of lables). In fact, you get more detail in some places (eg. more axis ticks). The reason this is a problem is that when you then apply the scaling down via iText, these items become very small and hard to read.

I have looked at the [Highcharts API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts) and cannot see a way to get Highcharts to scale up the contents rather than add more detail. How do I get this to work?

If the approach I am using is completely wrong, the wider question is how do I get print resolution server-side Highcharts charts? I have to use iText but am willing to try an alternative technology to do the chart rendering.

Comment: What is the format of the charts exported by Highcharts? Is there any way to get an output that consists of a vector image rather than a raster image? That would solve your problem of the low resolution.

Comment: highchart-serverside-export only outputs jpeg/png/tiff. Highcharts itself produces SVG output, but this tool doesn't give me access to the generated SVG.

Comment: I think [that doc](http://docs.highcharts.com/#export-module) will help you. Try to set exportin.scale and exportin.sourceWidth/height to get proper image width.

Answer (score 5):

try this

```
exporting: {
    sourceWidth: 1000,
    sourceHeight: 400,
},
```

> [Link to JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/exporting/sourcewidth/)

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the width of the exported image using the [`exporting.width`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#exporting.width) property.

This will not increase the size of the div or add/remove details or anything of that sort, it will simply scale the generated svg according to the specified width, maintaining the aspect ratio. Hence also scaling everything including texts etc.

```
exporting: {      
    width:2000    // or scale down to 100
}
```

[Upscaling exported images / pdf | Highcharts & Highstock @ jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/X32Kw/)

Comment: This looks promising. The API documentation doesn't really make it clear what the impact of this setting is. I played with it in jsfiddle and it looks like what I want. I'll test it properly when I get back to work.

Comment: Yes, even I spent (though learng SVG in the process) hours trying to create a custom implementation of scaling up the highchart generated SVG while trying to solve your rather interesting question. Eventually stumbled upon this :) @BurhanAli

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work. highcharts-server-export completely ignored the exporting section. I guess it doesn't use it. From what I understand, the exporting module is purely a client-side thing plus a web service for rendering. It sort of makes sense that highcharts-server-export doesn't use it as it is not client-side and external rendering is redundant.

Comment: @BurhanAli I had tried it with 2000px width png and i got the same on clicking on export